# Hide - Unhide backBarButton of UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, back-button

I want to do something like this.All controllers are pushed on navigation controller.
 ViewController 1 -> ViewController 2(Do not show back button which appears automatically by pushing) -> ViewController 3(Show Back button of navigation bar) -> ViewController 4(Again hide back Bar button).

I've tried setting title to empty for ViewController1 but then back button does not appear anywhere in the app. Also I've tried setting back bar button to nil before pushing ViewController2 on navigation stack. But nothing works as expected. Does someone knows how to do this. Note - I want default back bar button which appears when we push a viewController on stack not the left bar button item. If no option is left then i'll prefer left bar button item approach.

Answer (score 7):

I have done something similar to this before. In the controller that's going to push the next view controller that you don't want a back button in put this wherever you're doing your `pushViewController:`

```
myNextViewController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myNextViewController animated:YES];
```

In your case this would be in the 1st and 3rd viewControllers in the stack.

Comment: this hides back button for the next controller too. In my case ViewController3 also doesn't show back button

Comment: What if you put: `myThirdViewController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO;` before pushing it?

Comment: I've tried this also but it didn't work. You can try it yourself.

Comment: I'll try knock up a sample project and see how I go. I'm surprised that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The `hidesBackButton` approach shows a animation of the back bar button being pushed out. However small, like you said this doesn't seem right. The dirty option forward would be to do this in the parent view controller.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.title = @"Title";
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    self.title = @"";
}
```

**Original Answer**

You will need to add this to the view controllers where you want to hide the back button. Pretty self explanatory.

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

Comment: this hides the back button in whole application. even when i set it to true back button does not appear.I've tried this approach already.

Comment: Where did you set this? I have just tested this and it seems to working as expected.

Comment: I've set this on ViewController2's viewDidAppear Method

Comment: I want sometimes it to appear and sometimes disappear. on view controller2 because i'm using viewcontroller2 again somewhere in my application there i need the back bar button to be appear.

Comment: Check [this](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22783696/BlinkingTables.zip). It seems to be working fine. Am I doing something different?

Comment: Tested your code. Have you tried putiing these lines if ( !self.showNavigationItem ) 
        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
    else
        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO; into viewWillAppear or viewDidLoad?

Comment: It works but we can clearly see the back button hiding when pushing first view controller on stack

Comment: It's because we've done that in `viewWillAppear:` that it seems abrupt. Put the same code in `viewWillLoad` and it will animate out.

Comment: there is no method named "viewWillLoad"

Comment: I know. My bad. I meant `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: I see your point. I have updated my answer with another option. Probably not the best way forward, it works.

Comment: I've also already tried this. setting title to empty is not working either.